# How to check if there's a change in account balance during a given date range

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to write an SQL psuedo code  which returns a boolean  depending if there's change in balance maintained by the customer during any time within a specific date range given in reporting filter.

> [image: Any psuedo code change will]

Above is my sample teradata account table. Then i club additional tables and populate a fact which looks like

[image]

So if there's a change in balance between rows , the result should be 1, where as it should be zero if there is zero, since the balance havent changed during the time period.

How should i go about the logic of populating the column Change Indicator

Answer (score 2):

Do aggregation & use `case` expression :

```
select custid, date,
       (case when min(currentbalance) <> max(currentbalance) then 1 else 0 end)
from t
where date >= @startdate and date < @enddate
group by custid, date;
```

Comment: Hi Yogesh, how do i extend the same if at all i want to populate a extra column in new table with these boolean values , then should i check for each day?

Comment: @te. . . Add the column in group by too.

Comment: Hi Yogesh, really helps, can you help with code Where in i dont have to give the dates manually, but the code should check each row in my base table irrespective, and then populate the boolean in new table if there is a change after every row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select custid
from t
where date >= @range1 and date < @range2
group by custid
having min(balance) <> max(balance);
```

Or, if you just want the flag for a given customer and range:

```
select (case when min(balance) <> max(balance) then 1 else 0 end)
from t
where date >= @range1 and date < @range2 and
      custid = @custid
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and the new example data you need a *Windowed Aggregate*:

```
select ...
  ,case when LAG(current_balance) over (partition by custid order by datecol)
          <> current_balance 
        then 1
        else 0
   end as change_indicator
```

Comment: Thanks dnoeth, this is what i was looking for. Appreciate your help on this